# Calendar view in not updated for initial value in bootstrap date range picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, date-range

I have below code and on initial calendar is no selecting the range between start and end date as shown on the image.

[image]
My code is as below:

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            },
            //autoApply: true,
            autoUpdateInput: true,
            startDate: moment(),
            endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'months')
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startDate` should always be less than `endDate`.

**partially working demo(css issues)**:

[**https://fiddle.jshell.net/m68u9ctj/1/**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/m68u9ctj/1/)

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    },
    autoUpdateInput: true,
    startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'months'),
    endDate: moment()
});
```